# Azure Pipeline task which automatically deletes the backup files which are more than one week old

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have added a powershell task in a pipeline which takes the backup of files before deployment. Everyday we are doing builds multiple times a day and we are going to run into the server space issue frequently. Can you please help me for any possibility to add any task in the pipeline to modify the build script to delete the build backup files which are more than one week old. Here we have to manage automatically deletion of files through pipeline itself not from server side.

Regards,
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a powershell task to delete older backups than X days using a powershell devops task and a cron task.

Here is a powershell script to delete files from a folder that are older than x days.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "S:\folder" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-X))} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Cron schedule:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 10 * * *"
  displayName: Run pipeline based on schedule
  always: true
  branches:
    include:
    - main
```

Powershell task:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: remove old backup files from `S:\folder`
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
         Get-ChildItem -Path "S:folder" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-X))} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following powershell script to delete the files older than 7 days in power shell task.

```
Get-ChildItem –Path  "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder" –Recurse -include *.*| Where-Object { $_.CreationTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) } | Remove-Item -force  -recurse
```

The above will only delete old files, and the empty folders will still be there.

If you want to delete folders too, please use the following script . Note that with the following one, if you have a new file in a old folder, the whole folder will be deleted along with the new file.

```
Get-ChildItem –Path  "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder" –Recurse  | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) } | Remove-Item -force  -recurse
```